# Grant read access to my SQL Server database to all future SQL users

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Can I configure my SQL Server 2014 database so that any login that will be created in the future will have read access to it automatically?

Comment: Is it a problem to add newly to created user to a cusstom/sql server role that has access to that DB ?

Comment: I was hoping for a generic solution so we don't have to assign a role programmatically to every new SQL user

Comment: Could you supply us all with more information? Are you talking about SQL Server Login Accounts with individual password and/or Windows Authenticated Accounts in the SQL Server instance? Would you possibly be working with Active Directory Groups or not?

Answer (score 4):

To add on my comment, you can create a trigger on a database level and add user to desired role automatically when you create a user. You can add a custom one, but for example sake i added *db_datareader*.

Example :

```
    create trigger tg_AddUserToRole on database after CREATE_USER
    as
    declare @LoginName nvarchar(30)
    set @LoginName =  (select EVENTDATA().value('(EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','nvarchar(30)'))
    IF EXISTS(select 1 from sys.sysusers where name = @LoginName and  issqluser = 1)
    exec sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', @LoginName
```

Comment: He asked a solution for  " all users **with SQL Server authentication** " but your solution gives db_datareader to ANY created user.

Comment: Modified it. Good call!

Comment: So for this to work, all users need to be added to the database first. I wasn't clear about this before unfortunately: What I am after is that for all user logins that are created in the future on this database server, whether a user for this common/public database will be created or users will be added to other databases), all logins get read only access to the common/public database. Both users with SQL authentication and Windows authentication may access this common/public database actually.

Comment: @AlexandervanTrijffel It'd be helpful if you edit the original post with these clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

For new databases, add the user in the model database. This is used as the template for all new databases.

```
USE model
CREATE USER ... FROM LOGIN...
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', '...'
```

Copied from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550497/sql-server-give-a-login-permission-for-read-access-to-all-existing-and-future

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question if you want to distinguish between logins with `SQL Server Authentication` and `Windows Authentication`.

If you just want any user (every future user included) of this database to be able to read the data just 
grant `SELECT` to `public` database role.

If it's important to you that the principal is not `Windows` principal, in another answer with a `DDL-trigger` you should check if the login is authenticated by SQL Server.

Comment: I granted the public database role the SELECT permission for tables, schemas, all_columns, all_objects but a new sql user still cannot query from the database because 'The server principal "****" is not able to access the database "****" under the current security context.

Comment: >>>The server principal "****" is not able to access the database<<< means that user WAS NOT CREATED in this database

Comment: If you want everyone to be able to access this database without mapping any login just open guest: USE MYDB; GRANT CONNECT TO GUEST;

Comment: That's it, thanks! This is what I need.  USE MYDB
GRANT CONNECT TO GUEST; GRANT SELECT TO GUEST;